How to read exported Google Contacts using Emacs?
I exported my Google Contacts manually (from https://contacts.google.com/) to csv and vcf.
How can I read them easily using Emacs?
By reading I mean being able to browse them on an org file (e.g. org-contact) or a contact manager (e.g. EBDB).

https://github.com/jd/google-contacts.el was able to create an org-contact file by connecting to Google Contacts. However it appears it is no longer able to connect due to Google changes.
